# Python Lambda function calling postgres function - Not working correctly

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that calls a postgres function and return a value of 0 or 1. This postgres function main job is to use AWS_S3 extension to import a file in s3 into a table.

Running the function standalone in postgres works without any issues and is able to load the table. However, when calling it from Lambda, its not able load the table or return a value of 1 for success.

Below is the code of the postgres function, please let me know if I should change something in my function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION XSCHEMAX.import_match_data(
    IN p_table_name TEXT,
    IN p_column_name TEXT,
    IN p_format TEXT,
    IN p_bucket TEXT,
    IN p_filename TEXT,
    IN p_region TEXT
)  RETURNS INTEGER AS $$

DECLARE
    success_flag INTEGER := 0;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        EXECUTE '
            SELECT aws_s3.table_import_from_s3(
                $1,
                $2, 
                $3,
                aws_commons.create_s3_uri(
                    $4,
                    $5,
                    $6)
            );
        ' USING p_table_name, p_column_name, p_format, p_bucket, p_filename, p_region;
        
        success_flag := 1;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            success_flag := 99999;
    END;
    
    RETURN success_flag;;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Below is the snippet of code from my lambda where I make the call.

```
# PostgreSQL connection parameters
        db_params = {
            'host': secret_data['host'],
            'database': secret_data['database'],
            'user': secret_data['username'],
            'password': secret_data['password'],
            'port': secret_data['port']
        }
        
        # Connect to the PostgreSQL database
        connection = psycopg2.connect(**db_params)
        
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        
        # Truncate the MATCH_STAGE table
        cursor.execute("TRUNCATE TABLE XSCHEMAX.MATCH_STAGE;")
        connection.commit()

        # HEREEEE IS WHERE THE ISSUE - Call the PostgreSQL function
        cursor.execute("SELECT XSCHEMAX.IMPORT_MATCH_DATA(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)", 
                        (table_name, columns, format_options, bucket_name, file_path, region))
        
        # Fetch the result (success_flag)
        result = cursor.fetchone()[0]

        # Commit the transaction
        connection.commit()
        
        # Close the cursor and connection
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
```

I was able to execute the function from postgres without any issues using the following method.

```
SELECT XSCHEMAX.import_match_data('XSCHEMAX.MATCH_STAGE', 'match_record', '(format text)',  'dev-s3-bucket', 'Inbound/Administration/MatchResults.txt', 'us-east-1');
```

Comment: 1) As to not returning value, from docs [Return from function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING): *If you declared the function with output parameters, write just RETURN with no expression. The current values of the output parameter variables will be returned.* 2) As to table not being created, look at the Postgres log to see what is actually hitting database. Best guess permission error or you are pointing at wrong database.

Comment: Noted. I have added the return with no expression but that did not solve my problem. I have edited the code above to add the return statement.

Comment: Also, I cant be pointing to the wrong DB because I truncate the table first before calling " cursor.execute("SELECT XSCHEMAX.IMPORT_MATCH_DATA ....." and the truncate is successful. I'm able to see the table is empty

Comment: Read 2) from my original comment.

Comment: What do you mean by "its not able load the table"? Are you saying the Lambda function aborts with an error? If so, what is the error? If there is no error, then what is the contents of `result`?

Comment: There is no error. The results value is 0. The postgres function works fine running standalone using the method I mentioned above within my question. However, when trying to call/execute the postgres function from lambda, its not able to load the table with data. Is there a permission I'm missing for lambda to execute a postgres function?

Comment: Why when calling the postgres function from lambda always lands in the exception block and returns 99999? I'm confused. The truncate statement is getting executed successfully without any issues. Any ideas?

Comment: Until you either look at the Postgres log or trap the exception message per [Trapping errpts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) : *43.6.8.1. Obtaining Information about an Error* this is going nowhere.

Comment: Thanks @AdrianKlaver. Help me out with trapping the error. Which Exception should I use? There are so many of them. Apparently. the one I'm using in my postgres function above is not catching anything.

Comment: 1) The Exception is working because you are returning `99999` which is only set in the exception block. 2) You want the relevant information as shown in *Table 43.2. Error Diagnostics Items*, which you can use as  shown in the example below the table. Though I would probably use them as an argument to a `RAISE NOTICE`. 3) The easier way would be to look at the Postgres log as that information should show up there.